# CodeIgniter Admin Login issue

Tags: codeigniter

**helper function**

```
 function is_log_in()
    {
                 $CI =& get_instance();

                 $is_logged_in=$CI->session->userdata('vId');


                 if($is_logged_in!='')
                 {


                    return true;

                 }
                 else
                 {

                    return false;
                 }

    }
```

**admin controller file**

```
 public function index()
    {

        if(is_log_in())
        {
                        $data['orders']=$this->admin_model->orders();
                        $data['todayorders']=$this->admin_model->todayorder();
            $this->load->view('dashboard',$data);

        }
        else
        {

            $this->load->view('login'); 
        }



    }
```

> admin login is working on my localhost fine,but not on server on my system in
>   chrome,in my friends systems its working fine in chrome browser.Only In my system its not working..

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: admin login is not working in chrome browser,,on my pc but other pcs its working,,,,

Comment: when i do submit on login page its redirect base usr(in admin controller) that time its not calling index() function....automatically,,thats problem,,so its not login,,,some days ago its working,,,,

Comment: i also cleared cache ago

Comment: check that is it going to controller?

Comment: login page is coming so it may be going to admin controller file...but not going on index() function.....i debug index() function,,,some days ago its working,,,

Comment: index() function of controller file is not calling...but on localhost,,its working fine...

Comment: may b your path is wrong.. see in error log file

Comment: when i run http://www.adlaabadli.com/admin  then its only login page,,,but after http://www.adlaabadli.com/admin/index.php given path then its login..and index function of admin controller also called,,,some days its worked  this link http://www.adlaabadli.com/admin..

Comment: i also added .htaccess for remove index.php...its worked some days ago...

Comment: please guide me,,,

Comment: why are you using index.php

Comment: when i were using javascript alert for testing,,,,it was working..but after removing alert then yet its come,,,i removed browser history ...then yet its come,,,

Comment: remove the cache data. cookies sessions from your browser then try again.

Comment: i have clear all session,cache data from browser then alert comes..

Comment: in my pc,,when i write alert for testing ,,its come,,,but after i removed alert yet its come,,,i cleared all histroy,cache memory options,,,of browser yet its come,,,i do any change for testing,,its not any effect on it,,,its happen only my pc,,in my all friends pc is working fine,,,i also do firewall and antivirus  off...please help me...

Comment: please guide me,,,

Comment: when i run my website login page on browsers first time on day which is worked,,but second time i run its out put not changed same day,,,i cleared  history and cached memory all thing,,,yet its not changed output....first time only shows right result,,,for admin login in codeigniter,,ple help me..thanks